# JSON Parsing method not working for ios4 in iphone?

Tags: iphone, json

I used following code to get response from JSON response. It  working very nicely in ios5 but for ios4 it is not working. So what will be solution in ios4.

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestForServer returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];

    for(id key in res)
    {
        id value = [res objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }
```

Please help me if anyone knows ans of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSJSONSerialization` since it is only supported on iOS 5.0+ and Mac OS X 10.7+. I think you can also have a try with third-party [JSON Library](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

**>>>Edited**

[Jsonkit for both iOS4 and iOS5](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: Actually I enabled ARC in my project. When i add third party lib it's giving error in that lib. For release or retain statements. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

NSJSONSerialization is only support ios 5 , if you want json for both ios 4 and ios 5 , use [jsonKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

Answer (score 0):

@python: Regarding your comment about ARC. You can actually turn off ARC for specific files created with MRC. Go to Project settings --> navigate to "Build Phases" tab --> under "Compile Sources" tab --> write as "-fno-objc-arc" in the Complier Flags" section for the specific file for which you don't want to use ARC.