# Does JSONKit support ARC, or is there a fork that supports ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, jsonkit

According to these comments, JSONKit does not support ARC, and not even running with fobjc-no-arc setting in an ARC environment:
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/37

Comment: see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459444/json-parsing-method-not-working-for-ios4-in-iphone/10459696#10459696

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can still use JSONKit in your application with ARC.

I'm using it myself.

Select your project root in XCode 5, under `Targets` select your application then select the `BuildPhases` tab. Under `Compile Sources` double-click JSONKit.m and add the following compiler flags `-fno-objc-arc`.

Hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: Did you check for memory leaks using Instruments? The JSONKit developer himself said there's no guarantee it works in an ARC environment. The problems probably are the boundaries from ARC to non-ARC.

Comment: Didn't found any issues so far and i've been using it for a while. With that said, doesn't mean that there aren't any. I just haven't found any.

Comment: Worksforme too. I wonder how much @johnezang hates the fact that lazy ARC-loving devs are happily using his ARC-free and GC-free library. He might not care, but he also might introduce a feature upgrade which will absolutely not work with ARC :)

Comment: This was very helpful for using JsonKit and also other librabry that did not use ARC. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I use JSONKit in `ARC` project with the `-fno-objc-arc` in the JSONKit.m file in the compile Source settings.

And just some of the posts you linked to in your question already say it works.

Comment: Sure it may work but the question is, will it work without memory leaks? Did you check with Instruments?

Comment: I've not noticed any memory leaks.

Comment: I added the flag, doesnt work for me..! Build Fails wen i try to run it on device..!