# Parse json in objective-c for my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

i have a problem parsing my json data for my iPhone app, I am new to objective-C. I need to parse the json and get the values to proceed. Please help. This is my JSON data:

```
[{"projId":"5","projName":"AdtvWorld","projImg":"AdtvWorld.png","newFeedCount":"0"},{"projId":"1","projName":"Colabus","projImg":"Colabus.png","newFeedCount":"0"},{"projId":"38","projName":"Colabus Android","projImg":"ColabusIcon.jpg","newFeedCount":"0"},{"projId":"25","projName":"Colabus Internal Development","projImg":"icon.png","newFeedCount":"0"},{"projId":"26","projName":"Email Reply Test","projImg":"","newFeedCount":"0"},{"projId":"7","projName":"PLUS","projImg":"7plusSW.png","newFeedCount":"0"},{"projId":"8","projName":"Stridus Gmail Project","projImg":"scr4.png","newFeedCount":"0"}]
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459444/json-parsing-method-not-working-for-ios4-in-iphone/10459696#10459696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 5 or later you can use `NSJSONSerialization`. If you have your JSON data in a string you can do:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSData *data = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

**Edit** To get a specific value:

```
NSDictionary *firstObject = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *projectName = [firstObject objectForKey:@"projName"];
```

Comment: i tried it, but how would i get the value for individual key, like the value for "projName"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) library for parsing.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.14oranges.com/2011/08/how-to-use-jsonkit-for-ios-and-the-rotten-tomatoes-api/) on how to use it.
You will basically end up with a dictionary and use `objectForKey` with your key to retrive the values.

Answer (score 1):

[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

or

NSJSONSerialization(iOS 5.0 or later)

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) for reading and writing json.

Take a look at the [documentation here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.1/annotated.html) and get an idea of how to use it.

Essentially, for parsing, you just give the string to the SBJsonParser and it returns a dictionary with an objectForKey function.  For example, your code might look something like:

```
NSDictionary* parsed = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] objectWithString: json];
NSString* projId = [parsed objectForKey:@"projId"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SBJson

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *dicRes = [parser objectWithString:stringFromServer error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use third party classes. Objective-c already includes handling JSON.

The class `NSJSONSerialization` expects an `NSData` object or reads from a URL. The following was tested with your JSON string:

```
NSString *json; // contains your example with escaped quotes
NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData 
    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error]
```

For more options with `NSJSONSerialization` see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).