# Parsing JSON before iOS5

Tags: ios, json

Since it seems that `NSJSONSerialization` class is only available in iOS 5.0+ ([NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), is there another option to parse JSON objects prior that version?

Thanks

Comment: You can try implementing solution given in this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459444/json-parsing-method-not-working-for-ios4-in-iphone

Comment: what did google bring up?

Comment: What I found didn't make me clear the issue of supporting earlier iOS versions, and sometimes people ask things that look recurrent because related posts are pretty old and options for solving the issue may have changed

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).

I've used it prior to iOS5 and it has better performance, and is easier to use than SBJSON.

Answer (score 1):

SBJSON is great option, I have used in it two app store apps.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options on github, for example [SBJSON](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

There was no JSON support prior to iOS 5. You can use third party code from here:

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit